# Running Average in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

## Monthly Running Average with Daily SUMS on Graph

I have data as Follows (SAMPLE):

[image]

- There would be multiple Orders Per Day.
- Need to Track Number of Orders per Day. In a Graph. (This is Straight for forward with Order Column Defaulting to 1 and then summing it.)

**The thing that I would like to achieve is additional metric of 30-Day Moving average of along with the Daily Total of WorkOrders**

Sample of what I have already achieved in Data Studio:

[image]

Along with it, I want **Pseudocode**

```
SUM ( Order 
WHEN 
DATE =( DATEBETWEEN ( CurrentRowDATE , CurrentRowDate - 30) ) 
) / 30
```

This would be the Average of Orders Per Day for the Past 30 Days.

Would Really Appreciate any Pointers. Appreciate your help in Advance.

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible in DataStudio. But apparently, you're using Excel (or Google Sheets), so you can calculate things before sending the data to Data Studio.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by blending your data source with itself using a cross join. I used this sample data on Google Sheets:
[image: sample data]

Created the join:
[image: cross join]

Then created the table:
[image: table definition]

The formula for creating the running average:

```
SUM(
  IF(
    date (Table 2) BETWEEN DATETIME_SUB(date (Table 1), INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND date (Table 1),
    orders (Table 2),
    0
  )
) / 3
```